# SED- replace result at file with anther one

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace result at file with result of anther. Basically trying to replace ip address at netplan file,It does not work.

this is the sentence:

```
sed -i "s/$(cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml |grep - |head -n1 |tr -d "-" |awk -F / '{print $1}')/$(ip add show |grep ens160 |grep inet |awk '{print $2}' |awk -F / '{print $1}')/g" /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

[image]

Thanks in advance,

update:

found the problem needed to delete space
sed "s/$(cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml |grep - |head -n1 |tr -d "-" |awk -F / '{print $1}' |tr -d " " )/$(ip add show |grep ens160 |grep inet |awk '{print $2}' |awk -F / '{print $1}')/g" /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

Shay

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? I can see your command but I do not see a result or an error message.

Comment: It would help if you separate your commands and save as variables. Then you can check if these are fine and give us information on their output.

Comment: please add output of: `echo $(cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml |grep - |head -n1 |tr -d "-" |awk -F / '{print $1}')` and `echo $(ip add show |grep ens160 |grep inet |awk '{print $2}' |awk -F / '{print $1}')`

Comment: btw, there is `yq` to parse `yaml`.

Comment: Hi all, ubuntu 22.04, I am not getting any error but the comand dont replace the ip, I added the picture

Comment: Please don't add pictures of text, rather copy paste the text and format as code please. Thanks :-)

Comment: I add the results of the commands  by your request :)

Comment: Btw, easier to `grep` output from `ip` with `-o` flag: `ip -o add show | awk '$2=="ens160" && $3=="inet" {sub("/.*","",$4); print $4}'`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide (as text, not images) your input, and your desired output. We need to see `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` so we can understand what `cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml | grep - |head -n1 |tr -d "-" |awk -F / '{print $1}'` produces. Most likely it is the internal quotes that are breaking it, but we can't tell if you don't show us the input data.

Comment: I am adding text

Comment: Never mind found the problem needed to delete the space

Answer (score 0):

sed "s/$(cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml |grep - |head -n1 |tr -d "-" |awk -F / '{print $1}' |tr -d " " )/$(ip add show |grep ens160 |grep inet |awk '{print $2}' |awk -F / '{print $1}')/g" /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

Comment: Perhaps add a bit of explanatory text?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a whole lot more readable if you don't jam everything into one line:

```sh
from=$(cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml |grep - |head -n1 |tr -d "-" |awk -F / '{print $1}' |tr -d " " )
to=$(ip add show |grep ens160 |grep inet |awk '{print $2}' |awk -F / '{print $1}')

sed "s/$from/$to/g" /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

And awk itself can do what grep/head/tr can do:

```sh
from=$(
  awk '
    /-/ {                     # grep -
      gsub(/-/, "", $0)       # tr -d "-"
      split($0, a, "/")       # awk -F/ ...
      gsub(/ /, "", a[1])     # tr -d " "
      print a[1]
      exit                    # head -n1
    }
  ' /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
)

to=$(ip add show | awk '/ens160/ && /inet/ {split($2, a, "/"); print a[1]; exit}')

sed "s/$from/$to/g" /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```